# How do I left align a QMenu?

Tags: c++, qt

How do I left align the QMenu which is created after a button click?

I want the menu to be opened from the left of the button

```
void MyMenu::cppSlot()
    {
        QMenu *xmenu = new QMenu;
        xmenu->addMenu("A -> Setup");
        xmenu->addMenu("B -> Setup");
        xmenu->addMenu("C -> Setup");
        xmenu->addMenu("D -> Setup");
        xmenu->addMenu("E -> Setup");
        xmenu->addMenu("F -> Setup");
        xmenu->addMenu("G -> Setup");
        xmenu->setFont(QFont ("Courier", 10));
        xmenu->setFixedWidth(250);
        xmenu->setAutoFillBackground(true);
        QPalette palette=xmenu->palette();
        palette.shadow();
        xmenu->setPalette(palette);   
        xmenu->show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I am still putting out the solution for whoever needs help in the future. I had a similar problem where I wanted to open the menu from the `bottom-right` corner of the button. To implement this, I had to re-write the `eventFilter` and change the position of the popup menu with respect to the global coordinates. In your case, I am assuming you need it to be on the `bottom-left`? This is how it should be:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Show && obj == ui->myButton->menu()){
        ui->myButton->menu()->move(ui->myButton->mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,ui->helpButton->height())));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And somewhere in your code, preferably after you have initialized your `QMenu` and added it to the `button`, you will have to add this line:

```
ui->myButton->setMenu(helpMenu);     
helpMenu->installEventFilter(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

First, read documentation for `QMenu` [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmenu.html) . Read `QMenu::exec ()` and see if you can achieve your requirement. Or else, if you are trying to change the position of `menu-indicator` sub-control you can use `Qt Style Sheets` as follows.

```
QPushButton::menu-indicator {
     image: url(menu_indicator.png);
     subcontrol-origin: padding;
     subcontrol-position: left;
 }
```